# Using current datetime in the screenshot path is not working

Tags: python, selenium

I want to capture screenshot with current date and time stamp. And using f string format for that. But, the date format is not appearing correctly after the screenshot is stored. Also, the screenshot is a blank file.

Below is the code given which is being used:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now() 
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
self.driver.save_screenshot(f".\\Screenshots\\Add{dt_string}.png")


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRgar.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a separator between `Add` and `{dt_string}`.

Try:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now() 
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
self.driver.save_screenshot(f".\\Screenshots\\Add\\{dt_string}.png")
```